# ruby on rails rmagick can't use, cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick, cloud9

I am using cloud9.

I want to use gem 'rmagick', but using bundle, following error message occurs...

please help...

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory:
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20180204-XXXXXX-oyXXpq.rb extconf.rb checking for gcc... yes
>   checking for Magick-config... no checking for pkg-config... yes
>   Package MagickCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `MagickCore.pc' to the
>   PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'MagickCore' found
>   checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... *** extconf.rb
>   failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack
>   of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for
>   more details.  You may need configuration options.

Comment: Have you installed `imagemagick` ?

Answer (score 2):

I just spun up a Cloud9 VM and tried it.

My Cloud9 VM I tried used `yum` as a package manager. Meaning I installed ImageMagick via `sudo yum install ImageMagick-devel`... when I did that my `gem install rmagick` worked.

Didn't try it with Bundler, but if `gem install` works then it should work in Bundler also.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command prompt install/update `imagemagick` via

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

See [more](https://community.c9.io/t/install-imagemagick/3608/8)

Hope it helps